# Sort XML data by newest to oldest in PHP

Tags: php, html, xml, xml-parsing

I've got this code that works well now but thought it would be useful to have the Observed Data start from the newest date to the oldest.  How can I flip only the Observed Data?  Here is the code (Sorry if it doesn't look right on here, still getting use to posting on this site):

```
<?php
$url = "http://r7j8v4x4.map2.ssl.hwcdn.net/NOD_R.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
?>

<?php foreach ($xml->RESULTSET[0]->ROW as $MSG) :?>
<?php echo '<h4>', $MSG->MSG_TXT; '</h4>'; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
&nbsp;

<!-- Table Style -->
<style>
table {border: 2px solid #fff;}
table td {height: 15px;}
table td {border: 1px solid #fff; }
table tr {border: 1px solid #fff; }
table td {padding: 3px; }
</style>

<h2>Observed Data</h2>
<table>
<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
<thead>
<tr>
<td><span style="margin:0px; font-weight:bold">Day</span></td>
<td><span style="margin:0px; font-weight:bold">Time(EST)</span></td>
<td><span style="margin:0px; font-weight:bold">Reservoir Elev.(behind    dam)*</span</td>
<td><span style="margin:0px; font-weight:bold">Tailwater Elev.(below dam)*</span></td>
<td><span style="margin:0px; font-weight:bold">Avg Hourly Discharge*  </span></td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php foreach ($xml->RESULTSET[1]->ROW as $obs) :?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $obs->OBS_DAY; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $obs->OBS_HR; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $obs->UPSTREAM_ELEV; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $obs->DOWNSTREAM_ELEV; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $obs->AVG_HOURLY_DISCHARGE; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
</table>
<h2>Predicted Data</h2>
<table>
<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
<thead>
<tr>
<td><span style="margin:25px; font-weight:bold">Day</span></td>
<td><span style="margin:5px; font-weight:bold">Average Inflow* </span</td>
<td><span style="margin:5px; font-weight:bold">Midnight Elevation*</span></td>
<td><span style="margin:5px; font-weight:bold">Average Outflow*</span></td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php foreach ($xml->RESULTSET[2]->ROW as $pred) :?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $pred->PREDICTED_DAY; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $pred->DAILY_AVG_INFLOW; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $pred->MIDNIGHT_ELEV; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $pred->DAILY_AVG_OUTFLOW; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
</table>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read them into arrays before you output.

```
foreach ($xml->RESULTSET[1]->ROW as $obs) {
    $resultSet1[] = $obs;
}

foreach ($xml->RESULTSET[2]->ROW as $obs) {
    $resultSet2[] = $obs;
}
```

That will make it easier for you to reverse them. Once they're in arrays there are various ways to do it.  You can use `array_reverse`, a `for` loop with a decrementing index, or something like this:

```
<?php while ($obs = array_pop($resultSet1)) :?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $obs->OBS_DAY; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $obs->OBS_HR; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $obs->UPSTREAM_ELEV; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $obs->DOWNSTREAM_ELEV; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $obs->AVG_HOURLY_DISCHARGE; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```